# Conditional code snippets with React showing both cases

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show different code snippets based upon whether or not a `prop` exists, the code below however is rendering both cases - can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

```
{
    this.props.isParallax ?
    <Plx>
        <Component.../>
    </Plx> 
:
    <Component.../>
}
```

Comment: Both? at the same time? it has no sense...

Comment: Check this.. https://codesandbox.io/s/y07owwkoxz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the snippet below, your syntax is correct, you likely made a typo error somewhere else in your render :

```js
const Test = props => {
    return(
        <div>
            {props.isParallax ?
                <div>
                    <p>Totally a prallax lul</p>
                </div>
                :
                <p>Not a parallax</p>
            }
        </div>
    )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test isParallax/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

Are you sure that your ternary is encapsluated in a JSX component ?

Could you post more code ?

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```js
{
function() {
  this.props.isParallax ?
    return <Plx>
             <Component.../>
           </Plx>
  :
    return <Component.../>
}
}
```

Comment: It is the same thing as what he is trying to do.

Comment: This doesn't make sense and you are not calling the function either.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are missing the parenthesis enclosing the components. Can you please try with this

```
{
this.props.isParallax ?
(<Plx>
    <Component.../>
</Plx> )
:
   ( <Component.../>)
}
```

Comment: When we are returning a multi line statement, we have to enclose them in parenthesis.

Comment: It works without parenthesis as the `:` seperator does the same job